# How to remove text before a certain character?

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have the following values:

```
1 min 7 sec
23 sec
6 hours 10 min 14 sec
```

I want to return:

```
7 sec
23 sec
14 sec
```

Is there a way to do this in VBA?

Sec, Min, or Hours may not always be present if a value for it is not used.

I.e. if there are 60 seconds, it will just say 1 min. If there are 60 minutes exactly, it will just say 1 hour.

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  WHat have you tried?

Comment: I don't know why my post deserves a downvote, I am somewhat inexperienced with vba.

Comment: It's because there isn't any evidence of you attempting it yourself.  The fact it's not too intricate and that it's clear from your question what you desire, is why I attempted to answer it.  This site is more "Why doesn't this code work" rather than "Write my code for me."

Comment: I have not had to use VBA in a real life scenario. I read a book about it in 2015, but never actually had to use it for anything, so I didn't know where to even begin.

Comment: Understand that, but googling for example, gives this https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/181868-how-find-last-word-string-using-vba.html as the 2nd answer.   And, it's more than likely true that you wont understand any further scrutiny on solutions you may have chosen.

Comment: Before selecting a solution, I paste in pieces and google parts I don't understand to understand what is going on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a method using regular expressions. It looks for a number-space-sec and returns a hyphen if not found. Amend to suit.

Code amended to incorporate @Mathieu Guindon's suggestion. `+` looks for one or more instances, `*` for zero or more.

```
Function Regex1(v As Variant) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+\s*sec"
    If .Test(v) Then
        Regex1 = .Execute(v)(0)
    Else
        Regex1 = "-"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Comment: You could even make that whitespace optional, so both `5sec` and `5 sec` would work. RegEx FTW!

Comment: The `Test` method is a Boolean and checks if the search pattern is found. If true, return the matched pattern, if not, return hyphen (or whatever). Regular expressions is a whole new galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function POP(strInput As String) As String

Dim a() As String

a = Split(strInput, " ")

If UBound(a) > 0 Then

    POP = a(UBound(a) - 1) & " " & a(UBound(a))

Else

    POP = a(UBound(a))

End If

Erase a

End Function
```

Comment: This would return `sec`.

Comment: Apologies, I used test data like 1hr 20m 4sec

Comment: Yup, was having the same problem as BigBen

Comment: Do you also have to allow for the possibility of sec not being present at all? Not clear from the OP.

Comment: Upvoted Nathan_Savs post because it works. Experimenting with it some more for different scenarios before marking as the answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.